# Entity Framework Core query error when include subquery

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have this EF query

```
var r = (from cd in _context.CentoData
    .Where(c =>
        (string.IsNullOrEmpty(geneName) ? true : c.Gene == geneName) &&
        (string.IsNullOrEmpty(codingEffect) ? true : c.CodingEffect == codingEffect) &&
        (string.IsNullOrEmpty(zygosity) ? true : c.Zygosity == zygosity) &&
        (string.IsNullOrEmpty(sex) ? true : c.Sex == sex) &&
        (string.IsNullOrEmpty(clinicalStatement) ? true : c.ClinicalStatement == clinicalStatement) &&
        (onsetAge == null ? true : c.AgeAtDiagnosisYearsMonths < onsetAge))
    from gs in _context.GnomadSnv
    .Where(g => g.Chromosome == cd.Chromosome &&
        g.Position == cd.Position &&
        g.Ref == cd.RefNt &&
        g.Alt == cd.AltNt)
    .DefaultIfEmpty()
    select new resultType
    {
        name = cd.name,
        AF = g.AF
    }
```

And it works well. But when I when I include a `Contains` subquery as below (line 9), it pops error saying

> "The multi-part identifier "c.Chromosome" could not be bound".

`patients` is a string list with tens to hundreds elements.

```
var r = (from cd in _context.CentoData
    .Where(c =>
        (string.IsNullOrEmpty(geneName) ? true : c.Gene == geneName) &&
        (string.IsNullOrEmpty(codingEffect) ? true : c.CodingEffect == codingEffect) &&
        (string.IsNullOrEmpty(zygosity) ? true : c.Zygosity == zygosity) &&
        (string.IsNullOrEmpty(sex) ? true : c.Sex == sex) &&
        (string.IsNullOrEmpty(clinicalStatement) ? true : c.ClinicalStatement == clinicalStatement) &&
        (onsetAge == null ? true : c.AgeAtDiagnosisYearsMonths < onsetAge) && 
        (patients != null ? patients.Contains(c.RandomPatientId): true))
    from gs in _context.GnomadSnv
    .Where(g => g.Chromosome == cd.Chromosome &&
            g.Position == cd.Position &&
            g.Ref == cd.RefNt &&
            g.Alt == cd.AltNt)
    .DefaultIfEmpty()
    select new resultType
    {
        name = cd.name,
        AF = g.AF
    }
```

Did I miss something here?

Comment: This query needs some serious simplification. For starters, there's no reason to use ` (string.IsNullOrEmpty(geneName) ? true : c.Gene == geneName)`. Even in SQL such catch-all queries are bad. In an ORM they are simply not needed. If you don't want that parameter just *don't* add the expression. You can chain `Where()` calls to create the equivalent of `AND`. You can write eg `if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(geneName)) { query=query.Where(c=>c.Gene==geneName))}`

Comment: Second that `WHERE` looks like an attempt to join `c` and `gs` using pre-1990's syntax. That's frowned upon in SQL. LINQ probably doesn't even recognize it. Use a proper `join`, or add a relation between the tables or simply create a *view* that implements this query. EF is an ORM, not a replacement for SQL. Some things are simply easier to write in SQL, especially reporting queries like this one

Comment: Once you remove the redundant catch-all expressions, the `contains` line should be `if (patients != null){ query=query.Where(c=>patients.Contains(c.RandomPatientId));}`.

Comment: Thanks Panagiotis. I was trying to make the query flexible since the all params could be null. Your suggestions are appreciated

Comment: You don't have to make them flexible, they're already flexible. I'll repeat it, even in SQL such catch-all statements are a *bad* idea resulting in bad execution plans. Check [How to confuse the SQL Server Query optimizer](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/how-to-confuse-the-sql-server-query-optimizer/) for an explanation. With LINQ and an ORM you *don't* need such queries. You can simply create any query you want in code and even compose it from different parts